# Preventing mulitple instance of an asynctask, or creating a persistent boolean

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-activity

My objective is that onCreate of a particular activity will start running an Async-task "BackgroundTask".
  I want to make sure that only one BackgroundTask will run at any given time, so before calling .execute I want to first check to see if a Boolean is tripped to indicate another is already running.

I wish for this Async-task to run perpetually even if the app is not currently on screen.  It should only be closed if the user pushes a button to end it, or perhaps force closes the entire thing.

Question:

Can I create a Boolean who's value will never be reset by going to home screen or moving further into or outside of all the activities in my app?
I don't know enough about when or why Android loses saved variables in apps.

Comment: Isn't that what `Bundle` is for? [`Bundle.getBoolean`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#getBoolean(java.lang.String)), [`Bundle.putBoolean`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putBoolean(java.lang.String,%20boolean))

Answer (score 1):

You can save this boolean in your preferences like the following:

```
        boolean booleanValue = true;
    String somePreferencesKey = "SOME_PREFERENCES_KEY";
    SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    pref.edit().putBoolean(somePreferencesKey, booleanValue).commit();
```

And then, at any time in the future, you can get the saved boolean value from your saved preferences as follows:

```
        boolean booleanValue;
    String somePreferencesKey = "SOME_PREFERENCES_KEY";
    SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    booleanValue = pref.getBoolean(somePreferencesKey, false);
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Thanks,

Mohamed.

Comment: What will this boolean be able to live through, which other things could not?

Also can it be accessed and changed from anywhere?  I will need to check it from an activity, and set it from an Async task

Comment: This boolean will be available for the whole lifetime of your application, the only way this boolean gets deleted if you went to the Settings app and cleared your app data. So, it's will be available from whatever other screen/activity/asyctask or even from a background service to access it.